# Select top 5 in the last week from category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in MS SQL:

```
Category
 - Id (int)

CategoryElement
 - Id (int)
 - CategoryId (int) //References Category.Id
 - Time (datetime)
```

So, each category can have zero or more category elements. Time, in CategoryElement, represents the time when the category element was created.

I need some help writing the following query: order categories descending by the number of category elements added in the last 7 days and display category id and how many elements were added.

So far I managed to write they query without the "added in the last 7 days" part:

```
SELECT c.Id, e.ElemCount
FROM dbo.Categories AS c 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(1) AS ElemCount, MAX(Time) AS LatestElem
     FROM dbo.CategoryElements
     GROUP BY CategoryId) AS e 
ON c.ID = e.CategoryId
ORDER BY e.LatestElem DESC
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Date processing functions vary accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF` and the `WHERE` clause to get just the past week and `TOP 5` to limit the result to only 5 rows.

```
SELECT TOP 5 c.Id, e.ElemCount
FROM dbo.Categories AS c 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(1) AS ElemCount, MAX(Time) AS LatestElem
     FROM dbo.CategoryElements
     GROUP BY CategoryId) AS e 
ON c.ID = e.CategoryId
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, e.Time, GetDate()) < 7
ORDER BY e.LatestElem DESC
```

My answer above assumes use of SQL Server. Depending on your database type the code may change a little. For example, for MySQL it would be as follows:

```
SELECT c.Id, e.ElemCount
FROM dbo.Categories AS c 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(1) AS ElemCount, MAX(Time) AS LatestElem
     FROM dbo.CategoryElements
     GROUP BY CategoryId) AS e 
ON c.ID = e.CategoryId
WHERE (Date(now()) - Date(e.Time)) < 7
ORDER BY e.LatestElem DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I think your arguments in `DATEDIFF` are backwards.

Comment: They are, good catch. `DATEDIFF` is defined as `DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )`. I have made the necessary edits to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it is not giving the right result. The final count should contain only the number of elements added in the last week...

Comment: The query is returning only 5 results, based on the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at something like:

```
WHERE (Date(now()) - Date(Time)) < 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what RDBMS you're using, but in SQL Server you could do:

```
SELECT c.Id, e.ElemCount
FROM dbo.Categories AS c 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(1) AS ElemCount, MAX(Time) AS LatestElem
     FROM dbo.CategoryElements
     WHERE DATEDIFF(d, Time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= 7
     GROUP BY CategoryId) AS e 
ON c.ID = e.CategoryId
ORDER BY e.LatestElem DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "last 7 days" restraint would go in the subquery your inner joining on. Like so.

```
SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(1) AS ElemCount, MAX(Time) AS LatestElem
FROM dbo.CategoryElements
WHERE Time > dateadd(dd,-7,getDate()) -- 7 Days prior to today
GROUP BY CategoryId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CategoryId, count(*) as cnt
from CategoryElement
where dateadd(day, -7, getdate())<= Time
group by CategoryID
order by   count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(*) AS numbOfCat
FROM dbo.CategoryElement
WHERE [Time] BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY CategoryId
ORDER BY MAX(Time) DESC
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9b09/1)

If you need TOP 5 then

```
SELECT TOP 5 CategoryId, COUNT(*) AS numbOfCat
FROM dbo.CategoryElement
WHERE [Time] BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY CategoryId
ORDER BY MAX(Time) DESC
```